# WITH RECURSIVE SQL failed in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion

I'm trying to execute the following recursive query in PostgreSQL, but it complains

```
with
  animals as (
    select *
    from (values
      ('cat', 'feline'),
      ('feline', 'mammal'),
      ('dog', 'canidae'),
      ('canidae', 'mammal'),
      ('mammal', 'animal')
    ) as t (child, parent)
  ),
  recursive ranimals as (
      select child, parent
      from animals
      where child = 'cat'
    union
      select child, parent
      from animals a, ranimals ra
      where ra.parent = a.child
  )
select * from ranimals;
```

It fails with the following message:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ranimals"
LINE 12:   recursive ranimals as (
```

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is confusing.  The clause is `with recursive` for the entire `with`.  `recursive` is not a modifier on a given CTE.  So, try this:

```
with recursive
  animals as (
    select *
    from (values
      ('cat', 'feline'),
      ('feline', 'mammal'),
      ('dog', 'canidae'),
      ('canidae', 'mammal'),
      ('mammal', 'animal')
    ) as t (child, parent)
  ),
  ranimals as (
      select child, parent
      from animals
      where child = 'cat'
    union all
      select ra.child, a.parent
      from animals a join
           ranimals ra
           on ra.parent = a.child
  )
select * from ranimals;
```

I also fixed the `join` syntax, fixed the `select` to use table aliases for the column, and changed the `union` to `union all`.

This version actually runs.  [Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1) is a SQL Fiddle.